# Styling twitter bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter-Bootstrap buttons are awesomely beautiful. [Try them out by scrolling over them](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

[image: bootstrap button screenshot]

But they are limited in colors.

Is there any way I could change the base color of the button while keeping the beautiful hover-over effect that bootstrap has made so beautiful and effortless?

I am completely unaware of what the css/javascript looks like that twitter uses to maintain those effects.

Comment: Find and edit the less definitions of the buttons. Then recompile the CSS with `lessc`. **Don't edit the CSS files directly!** It's not maintainable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically, the buttons in Twitter Bootstrap are controlled in CSS by ".btn{}". What you have to do is go to the CSS file and find where it says "btn" and change the color settings. However, it's not as simple as just doing that since you also have to change what color the button changes into when you highlight it, etc. To do THAT, you have to look for other tags in CSS like ".btn:hover{}", etc.

Changing it requires changing of the CSS. Here is a quick link to that file:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: This isn't a particularly beautiful solution. Please use the other solutions, which are based on LESS. Or customize bootstrap via the variable editor on their website.

Comment: just override it... loading your css in the end can help you to solve the problem .. using same calss of bootstrap

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely be against modifying the bootstrap.css.  Like Jaimin said, just override it.

Answer (score 177):

I found the simplest way is to put this in your overrides.  Sorry for my unimaginative color choice

### Bootstrap 4-Alpha SASS

```
.my-btn {
  //@include button-variant($btn-primary-color, $btn-primary-bg, $btn-primary-border);
  @include button-variant(red, white, blue);
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 Alpha SASS Example](http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/LVKBby)

### Bootstrap 3 LESS

```
.my-btn {
  //.button-variant(@btn-primary-color; @btn-primary-bg; @btn-primary-border);
  .button-variant(red; white; blue);
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 LESS Example](http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/nsEJf)

### Bootstrap 3 SASS

```
.my-btn {
  //@include button-variant($btn-primary-color, $btn-primary-bg, $btn-primary-border);
  @include button-variant(red, white, blue);
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 SASS Example](http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/aArJt)

### Bootstrap 2.3 LESS

```
.btn-primary {
  //.buttonBackground(@btnBackground, @btnBackgroundHighlight, @grayDark, 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.75));
  .buttonBackground(red, white);
}
```

[Bootstrap 2.3 LESS Example](http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/EHnkq)

### Bootstrap 2.3 SASS

```
.btn-primary {
  //@include buttonBackground($btnPrimaryBackground, $btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight); 
  @include buttonBackground(red, white); 
}
```

It will take care of the hover/actives for you

From the comments, if you want to lighten the button instead of darken when using black (or just want to inverse) you need to extend the class a bit further like so:

### Bootstrap 3 SASS Ligthen

```
.my-btn {
  // @include button-variant($btn-primary-color, $btn-primary-bg, $btn-primary-border);
  $color: #fff;
  $background: #000;
  $border: #333;
  @include button-variant($color, $background, $border);
  // override the default darkening with lightening
  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &.focus,
  &:active,
  &.active,
  .open > &.dropdown-toggle {
    color: $color;
    background-color: lighten($background, 20%); //10% default
    border-color: lighten($border, 22%); // 12% default
  }
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 SASS Lighten Example](http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/EaLaBe)

Comment: How would you translate this into scss?

Comment: Then run `lessc` to compile your changes to CSS.

Comment: Dreyfuzz I do not use scss but looking at the [3rd party sass bootstraps](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss) it seems you would do
`.btn-primary {@include buttonBackground($btnPrimaryBackground, $btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight); }`
`

changing your variables appropriately  (sorry for terrible formatting)

Comment: I get `.buttonBackground is undefined in main.less` do I need to include anything in my less?

Comment: @hmajumdar make sure you have the bootstrap less or sass framework imported first, then add the overrides after.  If you are getting `buttonBackground undefined` you either don't have the framework or are using the old 2.3 and should switch to `button-variant` for v3.  I added some codepen examples with the bare minimum files to include (tho likely you want more than just those)

Comment: @Andre hover does actually work, you just can't see it because black is as dark as it can go.  If you look at the source code https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/buttons.less you will see they are applying a `darken` method to all of your colors.  Since you are picking black it can't darken it anymore.  Pick a lighter color or check out this version where I flip it so it lightens instead of darkens: http://codepen.io/chrisan/pen/EaLaBe

Comment: Does anyone else just set the value of `$brand-warning`; the variable seen [in Bootstrap 3's official SASS code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L18)  which is the input for `button-variant` (I believe)? This works for me. Seems to be the way they intended... And if `$brand-warning` change would affect other areas you don't want; just c hange `$btn-default-color` [or other variables which only affect buttons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L168)

Answer (score 33):

You can overwrite the colors in your css, for example for Danger button:

```
.btn-danger { border-color: #[insert color here]; background-color: #[insert color here];

.btn-danger:hover { border-color: #[insert color here]; background-color: #[insert color here]; }
```

Comment: I think you need to style `:focus` and `:active` too, or otherwise you sometimes get weird colours on clicks/drags...

Comment: Simple, I like it.

Comment: For those who found this via searching, and you're getting a default color when you click and drag off a button, you need `.btn-primary:active:focus {` in order to select and override that case

Answer (score 27):

Here is a good resource: http://charliepark.org/bootstrap_buttons/

You can change color and see the effect in action.

Comment: This is a configurator. It's easy if you are in a hurry creating a prototype for the customer. However not maintainable in the long term. What if the configurator disappears? Therefore for the real thing, `lessc` is a better solution.

Comment: Love this solution, though I wish there was a way to enter rgb/rgba to get the exact colors.

Comment: @nalply less is great if you've already got that step going, but this "configurator" does everything needed to generate css.  Drop it in and go.  You won't need the configurator after that.

Answer (score 21):

If you are already loading your own custom CSS file after loading bootstrap.css (version 3) you can add these 2 CSS styles to your custom.css and they will override the bootstrap defaults for the default button style.

```
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {

  background-color: #A6A8C1;
  border-color: #31347B;
 }

.btn
{
  background-color: #9F418F;
  border-color: #9F418F;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of changing CSS values one by one I would suggest to use [LESS.](http://lesscss.org/) Bootstrap has LESS version on Github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

LESS allows you to define variables to change colors which makes it so much more convenient. Define color once and LESS compiles CSS file that changes the values globally. Saves time and effort.

Answer (score 11):

In order to completely override the bootstrap button styles, you need to override a list of properties. See the below example.

```
    .btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus, 
    .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:visited,
    .btn-primary:active:hover, .btn-primary.active:hover{
        background-color: #F19425;
        color:#fff;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
```

If you don't use all the listed styles then you will see the default styles at performing actions on button. For example once you click the button and remove mouse pointer from button, you will see the default color visible. Or keep the button pressed you will see default colors. So, I have listed all the pseudo-styles that are to be overridden.

Comment: this method is great. it's second only to the LESS bootstrap customization

Answer (score 9):

For Bootstrap for Sass override it's

```
.btn-default {

    @include button-variant($color, $background, $border);

}
```

You can see the source for it here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/a5f5954268779ce0faf7607b3c35191a8d0fdfe6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss#L6

Answer (score 5):

Or try http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/. It creates css for buttons based on html color input. Add the css after the bootstrap css. It provides three styles of buttons (light, dark and spin).

Comment: This is a configurator (sort of). It's quite easy if you are in a hurry creating a prototype for the customer. However not maintainable in the long term. What if the configurator disappears? Therefore for the real thing, `lessc` is a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very easy and eficient  way: 
add in your CSS your class with the colors you want to apply to your button:

```
.my-btn{
    background: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.my-btn:hover { 
  border-color: #C0C0C0; 
  background-color: #C0C0C0; 
}
```

and add the style to your bootstrap button or link:

```
<a href="xxx" class="btn btn-info my-btn">aaa</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

In [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitterbootstrap.org) bootstrap 3.0.0, 
Twitter button is flat. 
You can customize it from http://getbootstrap.com/customize. Button color, border radious etc.

Also you can find the HTML code and others functionality 
http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-css-buttons.

Bootstrap 2.3.2 button is gradient but 3.0.0 ( new release ) flat and looks more cool.

and also you can find to customize the entire bootstrap looks and style form this resources: 
http://twitterbootstrap.org/top-5-customizing-bootstrap-resources/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but just to add another perspective. I'd assert that using overrides is really a bit of a code smell and will quickly get out of hand on larger projects. Today you're overriding Buttons, tomorrow Modals, the next day it Dropdowns, etc., etc.

I'd advise to try possibly commenting out the include for `buttons.less` and either define my own, or, find another Buttons library that's more suitable to my project. Shameless plug: here's an example of how easy it is to mix our Buttons library with TB: [Using Buttons with Twitter Bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhTFwq0vjLw&list=UUF1MSa97IFUc_aPVxoCSn0g). In practice, again, you'd likely want to remove the `buttons.less` include altogether to improve performance but this shows how you can make things look a bit less "generic". I haven't done this exercise yet myself but I'd imagine you could start by simply commenting out lines like:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less#L17

And then recompiling using `lessc using one of your own buttons modules. That way you get the battle tested core of TB but can still customize things without resorting to major overrides. There's absolutely no reason not to use only parts of a library like Bootstrap. Of course the same applies to the Sass version of TB

Answer (score 1):

You can change  background-color and use !important;

```css
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #003c79 !important;
  border-color: #15548b !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #4289c6 !important;
  border-color: #3877ae !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
   background-color: #4289c6 !important;
   border-color: #3877ae !important;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap (at least for version 3.1.1) and LESS, you can use this:

```
.btn-my-custom {
    .button-variant(@color; @background; @border)
}
```

This is defined in `bootstrap/less/buttons.less`.