# Bootstrap color individual buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

So I've been trying a whole bunch of things to change the color of my buttons in a bootstrap website. I've tried [creating a class in the css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674614/can-i-change-bootstrap-button-color) and changing the background color there. I've tried using ids to change the background color, I've tried overriding .btn-primary, but that changes all of the buttons. I have more than 6 buttons to make more than 6 button colors, so I need to be able to do it without using the 6 existing button types. Does anyone know how I could do this?

The HTML:

```
<form action="index.html">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block home" id="home">
        Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

The CSS:

```
.home{
    background-color:#9b59b6;
}
```

Edit: 
Thank you all for your responses. They were all correct. However none of them fixed the issue. You know what did? Removing a lone / character that had somehow found its way into my code. Lesson learned: Check your code for other errors before blaming bootstrap and css.

Comment: Some ideas: 1) What happens if you force your `background-color` with `!important`? Maybe your definition is too weak in the definition hierarchy? 2) Consider the LESS definitions and that your CSS may be rewritten (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659070/styling-twitter-bootstrap-buttons), comment of nalply) 3) What do you see if you chose "Insepct Element" with your browser? Where is the color definition acutally coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new classes for your custom buttons like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-home">Home</div>
```

css:

```
.btn-home {
    background-color: #9b59b6;
    border-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Change how it looks when hovered or clicked */

.btn-home:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    border-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-home:active {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8a3n6om3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can make your own buttons something like `btn-one btn-two btn-three`

and style like like the following example

```
.btn-one {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-one:hover,
.btn-one:focus,
.btn-one.focus,
.btn-one:active,
.btn-one.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-one {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
```

and change the colors to your own needed colors