# How do I style a twitter bootstrap button with a hexadecimal color in Rails 4.2.4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am a junior developer building my first web application for a client.

The owner is not content with the standard colours of the bootstrap buttons on the home.html.erb and wants a flamboyant colour of pink on one button particularly.

How do I style a twitter bootstrap button with hexadecimal colour using rails 4.2.4

What would the syntax be and what CSS folder from my below list would I use for such:

```
bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss,
home.css.scss,
pages.scss
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change Bootstrap button color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674614/can-i-change-bootstrap-button-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it to the `application.css|css.scss`

So if you added a class of `btn btn-pink` to the `button`. I recommend that you add `btn` class so you will inherit the basic styling.

```
.btn-pink{
  color: #FFFFFF; // whatever you want
  background-color: ##FF69B4; // whatever you want
}
```

Comment: so I understand you properly: right now in the home.html.erb i have.. class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"    Do I change this syntax in the embedded ruby to .btn-pink and also use this in the styles

Comment: Your code will become `... class: "btn btn-pink btn-lg" ...` and don't forget to add the styling the `application.css`

Comment: Really appreciate that. just one final query. Why the application.css file for styles deployment? as opposed to the bootstrap_and_cutomization.css.scss (or the page specific home.css.scss

Comment: You can put your custom `css` wherever you want as long as it's loaded in the `application.css` using `require` or `require_tree`.